# How do I interpret my autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation of COVID-19 time series data?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity, covid-19

Note: I've edited my question based on comments from @whuber.

I have a time series of the USA's COVID-19 daily deaths smoothed to mitigate massive, weekly data dumps. My two-plus years of data comes from *Our World in Data*. I have a simple Pandas data frame indexed by day and one column with the values. I tested the time series for stationarity with the Dickey-Fuller test (from StatsModels in Python) with the following results: an ADF of -3.16 and a p-value of 0.02. I understand the results to mean that my time series is stationary, but I'm not certain. My ACF and PACF are: [image]

Hence, I applied a difference to my time series for a new ADF of -4.38 and a p-value of 0.0. The ACF and PACF became: [image]

The new PACF, in particular, shows correlated lags that are perfect multiples of 7. These appear to be data dumps.

I don't know much about interpreting the results and would appreciate any input, but the second ACF and PACF seem to show that my time series is almost random-—like a random walk.

(1) How do I interpret *negative* correlations in my ACF and PACF?

(2) Thus far, my best predictive model is a baseline, persistence model that shifts all data by one day. Do the second ACF and PACF show potential for forecasting with DNNs?

(3) What's the best interpretation here?

Comment: The labels on the horizontal axis appear to be off by 1: there shouldn't be two spikes at 0 and 1 and the spikes at 8, 15, 22, etc. in the PACF clearly reflect the weekly reporting cycle and should appear at lags that are perfect multiples of 7.

Comment: I've edited my question above given your comments. How would you interpret things now? @whuber